# LineString shows only a point at (0.0) of my map

Tags: openlayers

I want to draw and connect 2 points in my map application. But i get a point at the same location even when i change the coordinates.

```
addLine(){
var points = [
  [78.65, -32.65], [-98.65, 12.65]
];

let layerLines = new LayerVector({
  source: new SourceVector({
    features: [new Feature({
      geometry: new LineString(points),
      name: 'Line'
    })]
  }),
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 10
    })
  })
}); 
this.map.addLayer(layerLines);
console.log(layerLines);
}
```

The application is developed Angular. you can see the image for more detail of the error.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map use projection EPGS 3857 by default (in meters) while your coordinates are in lat-long (in degrees), so they are located around point 0;0.

Try projecting your coordinates first

```
var points = [
  ol.proj.fromLonLat([78.65, -32.65]),
  ol.proj.fromLonLat([-98.65, 12.65])
];
```

Comment: ohh thanks. A small question is : can I have any chance to show the arrow sign instead of the line to show where it comes from and where it goes?

Comment: @myadsmail Please write a new question for different topics, though [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606206/draw-arrow-without-using-any-image-in-openlayers3) explains how to show an arrow